# How to service error if there is not specific key, but it should be

Tags: javascript, object, promise, fetch

I'm using fetch on `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=wiedzmin` . If you go to this link you can see that it is not any `volumeInfo.authors` in 9th object (from line 545 to 602).
It gives me an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined
```

I would like to make a logic like "if there is an error return "No value found" , and code execution will go further.

my piece of code:

```
fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=wiedzmin")
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(x => {

      console.log('AUTHORS: ')
        for(let i=0; i <= x.items.length - 1; i++){
          console.log(x.items[i].volumeInfo.authors.join(', '))
          }

      })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try check `x.items[i].volumeInfo.authors` if it is `undefined` then default empty array let the error would not occur:

```
fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=wiedzmin")
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(x => {
      console.log('AUTHORS: ')
      for(let i=0; i <= x.items.length - 1; i++){
          console.log((x.items[i].volumeInfo.authors || []).join(', '))
      }
    })
```

Or if you want ignore `x.items[i].volumeInfo.authors` is `undefined`, You still can use if:

```
fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=wiedzmin")
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(x => {
      console.log('AUTHORS: ')
      for(let i=0; i <= x.items.length - 1; i++){
        if(x.items[i].volumeInfo.authors) {
          console.log(x.items[i].volumeInfo.authors.join(', '))
        } else {
          console.log('No value found')
        }
      }
    })
```